# MatLab BayesNetToolbox parameter learning

Tags: matlab, nan, bayesian-networks, dirichlet

My question is specific to the "learn_params()" function of the [BayesNetToolbox](http://bnt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/usage.html#prior) in MatLab. In the user manual, "learn_params()" is stated to be suitable for use only if the input data is fully observed. I have tried it with a partially observed dataset where I represented unobserved values as NaN's.

It seems like "learn_params()" can deal with NaNs and the node state combinations that do not occur in the dataset. When I apply dirichlet priors to smoothen the 0 values, I get 'sensible' MLE distributions for all nodes. I have copied the script where I do this.

Can someone clarify whether what I am doing makes sense or if I am missing
something, i.e. the reason why "learn_params()" cannot be used with partially
observed data.

The MatLab Script where I test this is here:

```
% Incomplete dataset (where NaN's are unobserved)
Age = [1,2,2,NaN,3,3,2,1,NaN,2,1,1,3,NaN,2,2,1,NaN,3,1]; 
TNMStage = [2,4,2,3,NaN,1,NaN,3,1,4,3,NaN,2,4,3,4,1,NaN,2,4];
Treatment = [2,3,3,NaN,2,NaN,4,4,3,3,NaN,2,NaN,NaN,4,2,NaN,3,NaN,4];
Survival = [1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1];
matrixdata = [Age;TNMStage;Treatment;Survival];
node_sizes =[3,4,4,2];

% Enter the variablesmap
keys = {'Age', 'TNM','Treatment', 'Survival'};
v= 1:1:length(keys);
VariablesMap = containers.Map(keys,v);

% create the dag and the bnet
N = length(node_sizes); % Instead of entering it manually
dag2 = zeros(N,N);
dag2(VariablesMap('Treatment'),VariablesMap('Survival')) = 1;
bnet21 = mk_bnet(dag2, node_sizes);
draw_graph(bnet21.dag);
dirichletweight=1;

% define the CPD priors you want to use
bnet23.CPD{VariablesMap('Age')} = tabular_CPD(bnet23, VariablesMap('Age'), 'prior_type', 'dirichlet','dirichlet_type', 'unif', 'dirichlet_weight', dirichletweight);
bnet23.CPD{VariablesMap('TNM')} = tabular_CPD(bnet23, VariablesMap('TNM'), 'prior_type', 'dirichlet','dirichlet_type', 'unif', 'dirichlet_weight', dirichletweight);
bnet23.CPD{VariablesMap('Treatment')} = tabular_CPD(bnet23, VariablesMap('Treatment'), 'prior_type', 'dirichlet','dirichlet_type', 'unif','dirichlet_weight', dirichletweight);
bnet23.CPD{VariablesMap('Survival')} = tabular_CPD(bnet23, VariablesMap('Survival'), 'prior_type', 'dirichlet','dirichlet_type', 'unif','dirichlet_weight', dirichletweight);

% Find MLEs from incomplete data with Dirichlet prior CPDs
bnet24 = learn_params(bnet23, matrixdata);

% Look at the new CPT values after parameter estimation has been carried out
CPT24 = cell(1,N);
for i=1:N
s=struct(bnet24.CPD{i}); % violate object privacy
CPT24{i}=s.CPT;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of the BNT documentation, you need to make a couple of changes:

1. Missing values should be represented as empty cells instead of `NaN` values.
2. The `learn_params_em` function is the only one that supports missing values.

My previous response was incorrect, as I mis-recalled which of the BNT learning functions had support for missing values.

Comment: @ Kaelin, Thanks a lot for your answer. I will definitely compare the two as you suggest. Do you know the mathematical answer to how bayes_update_params() supports missing values? Does it just ignore them (as learn_params() does) or replace missing data with something?  [Yes, I will analyse the function.]

Comment: Yes, I agree after reading a bit more on this. When you keep missing values as NaN's, MatLab automatically ignores those cells when counting occurences of different states for Maximum Likelihood Estimation. This is not quite listwise deletion but something similar.